# AWS Lambda- Does the deployment package use /tmp?

Tags: aws-lambda

I need to create a Lambda function using a deployment package. The deployment package zip is about 50 MB. I would like to know if the deployment package will be unzipped into /tmp folder at runtime?

I know there is a limit of 512 MB on the /tmp storage. I plan to copy files from S3 to /tmp for local processing, so I would like to know how much real storage would be available in /tmp in my case.

Comment: may be worth looking at **lambda layers**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tmp **directory storage is separate** from the deployment package so you will have all 512 MB. The deployment package size is up to 50 MB in zip form and 250 MB in unzipped files. So, you can rely on 512 MB.

See related documentation: [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

Comment: Thanks. I did check the AWS Lambda limits page before, but this was not evident from the information in the page.

Comment: It's not evident from that information on the page at all; what is the source of your information @AndriyIvaneyko?  If you have another source, are you also able to comment on the impact of layers - are they also separate from the `/tmp` space?

Comment: @ElYobo Yes, it's not obvious from the documentation page, but by assuming contradiction you can find out that directory storage is separate, by reasoning. I agree with you that it's not evident, so it's subject to change by documentation owners.

Comment: I'm unable to make the same deduction as you @AndriyIvaneyko :)  Can you explain further how you determine that from information on that page?

Comment: @ElYobo Implying contradiction to the statement above will require a lot of notes  in the documentation, to prevent further problems during work with lambdas, those notes are missing + documentation is carefully maintained from that I've concluded following statement.

Answer (score 1):

As Andriy Ivaneyko has answered, every lambda function gets a /tmp folder which it can use for intermediate processing

But there are some side effects -

1. The /tmp folder is retained across lambda function invocations.
2. So when the next instance of the same lambda function is executing, this next instance may have access to the files stored/used by the first invocations.
3. You will need to explicitly clean the /tmp folder before completing the execution of the lambda function.

Comment: Are you able to provide a source in the AWS docs that makes that clear?

Comment: `/tmp` may store data across invocations but it acts as a transient cache and thus the data there is ephemeral, subject to being overwritten at any time - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps

If you need persistent storage, it's better to rely on S3 or EFS.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not mentioned about run time memory allocation of deployment packages.They have only specified maximum **Deployment package size**. Source [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

Though, as per the[AWS Lambda Execution Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html), Each execution context provides 512 MB of additional disk space in the /tmp directory. As per my understanding, on real time you will get 512 MB of disk space.

I hope it helps!